# Including framework XML documentation files in bin directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

My asp.net site is consuming its own XML documentation files to generate help pages. This is all working fine and I'm generating links between pages based on `<see>` and `<seealso>`, as well as the parameter types for methods. All the links work fine provided the linked to types also have XML files in my bin folder (that's the only location I'm searching).

For .NET framework types, there *are* XML files available, in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`. But these are only present on developer/build machines - they won't (so far as I'm aware) be present on the web server where this project ends up being hosted.

It would be convenient if the XML documentation files (for the framework assemblies that I reference) could be copied into the `bin` directory as part of our build process. Is there any neat way to do this? I could do a bulk copy of all of the XML files, but there are a lot of framework assemblies that we *don't* reference, and I don't want to bulk up the deployment by too much.

Comment: Are those folders not created on the target machine as part of the .Net framework installation? Or are they installed as part of Visual Studio?

Comment: @levelnis - From what I recall, they're installed by the .NET Framework SDK (which has been subsumed into the Windows SDK these days)

Comment: Forgive me if I'm asking obvious and foolish questions, but can you not install the Windows SDK on the target server? How much control do you have over the target machine?